# How to take input as operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a calculator but little bit different.
I'm thinking if a get input as operation like:

```
first_number = input('Type first number: ')
first_operation = input('Type your operation (+, -, *, /): ')
second_number = input('Type second number: ')
first_answer = input('Do you wanna stop here y/n: ')
if first_answer = "y":
   print(int(first_number), str(first_operation), int(second_number))
```

At the moment, the program needs to make a problem with user's input. For example, if user types `3` for first number, `+` for first operation, `2` for second number. I can only write those inputs like `3 + 2`, but I want to solve after print answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the operations from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module and create a dictionary of the available operators:

```
>>> from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
>>> ops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv}
```

After doing this you can use `first_operation` as the `key` on `ops`, get the corresponding function for the operation and supply `first_number` and `second_number` as its arguments:

```
>>> first_number = int(input('Type first number: '))
>>> second_number = int(input('Type second number: '))
>>> first_operation = input('Type your operation (+, -, *, /): ')
```

Let's say we enter `5` and `10` and `+`, then:

```
>>> print(ops[first_operation](first_number, second_number))
15
```

Note, the numbers are wrapped in `int` before supplying them to the operator since they behave differently when of type `str`.

As a simple alternative, you could use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) module, supplying it an expression as input:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> first_number = input('Type first number: ')
>>> second_number = input('Type second number: ')
>>> first_operation = input('Type your operation (+, -, *, /): ')
```

Here you don't need to change anything to `int`, you just join all arguments and make a string of the overall expression and feed it to `literal_eval` for it to do its thing.

```
>>> literal_eval(" ".join([first_number, first_operation, second_number]))
```

In essence your call will look like:

```
>>> literal_eval('5 + 10')
```

With a result of 15, again.